# Can Mathematica identify formulae or sequences of numbers?

Tags: numerics, symbolic

Can *Mathematica* suggest what a formula means? For example if I input

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i$$

can it infer that this is a sum of integer values from $0$ to $n$? Or if I enter $0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13$, can *Mathematica* tell me that these are Fibonacci numbers?

Answer (score 11):

`FindSequenceFunction` and `FindGeneratingFunction` will attempt to identify how the list was produced.

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55}, n]
```

> Fibonacci[n]

```
FindSequenceFunction[{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13}, n]
```

[image]

```
FindGeneratingFunction[{0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13}, n]
```

[image: out]

---

Comment: No, I mean something like: if I will 'give' mathematica a sequence: 0,0,1,2,3,5,8,13 it will return info that this are Fibonacci numbers, if I will give: 0,1,2,3,4,5 it will return info that this are integer values etc. But not just 'read' what it see, be give me an more precise answer

Comment: Now it is what I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you call the wolfram alpha api from inside mathematica then some of the returned data will be that sort of information.

Comment: google gets it straight away too..

Comment: And http://oeis.org  may be the best resource of all.

Comment: [OEIS in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40/is-it-possible-to-invoke-the-oeis-from-mathematica)