# Is there a notebook to create entries for OEIS?

Tags: notebooks

Is there a notebook to create entries for OEIS?

I seem to recall something like this a few years ago, but I haven't been able to find one. It might be from MathWorld. Any suggestions?

**Edit** If I had searched my old posts, I would have found a reference to EISFormat.m (which I can't find). However, I found [OEIS.m](http://oeis.org/wiki/User:Enrique_P%C3%A9rez_Herrero/OEIS_Package#Mathematica_OEIS_Package) which provides input from OEIS.

Comment: What exactly do you recall this Notebook doing?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think it set up all the sections on OEIS in their proper formats. I'm not sure if it provided a method to post on OEIS.

Comment: Just a link, I haven't tested it http://www.brotherstechnology.com/math/oeis_mathematica.html

Comment: @belisarius, it's probably a variation of the one in my edit above. If someone answers, I can check it off; or I could delete the OP. What do you think?

Comment: Have you seen [Is it possible to invoke the OEIS from Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40/is-it-possible-to-invoke-the-oeis-from-mathematica)? Actually Szabolcs reply.

Comment: My link above is also mentioned in another answer to the question linked by @Lou

Comment: Have you seen [Multipurpose Package for using OEIS data into Mathematica]( http://psychedelic-geometry.github.io/OEIS-Mathematica), quote: Multipurpose Package for using OEIS data into Mathematica

This package provides various utilities for searching and working with the information on The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. http://oeis.org/