# Is it possible to use an OEIS sequence as a function in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

For example, something like `A000040(n)` which would be equivalent to `Prime[n]`. Something that will return the appropriate term number with nothing more than a reference to the OEIS entry. This must be done only in *Wolfram Alpha*.

This post I find is NOT a duplicate since I am asking whether or not it is possible to do this completely from *Wolfram Alpha*. This means NO Mathematica. Therefore it is not a duplicate to [Is it possible to invoke the OEIS from Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40/is-it-possible-to-invoke-the-oeis-from-mathematica)

Comment: The closest you can get is "OEIS A000040 terms", but I can't get it to only list the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ term

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, then it is off topic because we don't take questions about Wolfram|Alpha that aren't concerned with engaging with it from Mathematica.

Comment: As noted by m_goldberg and as noted [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (which *you* should have at least glanced at), pure Alpha questions are off-topic on this site; you can prolly try asking on Community instead.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I'll go ask there. However, I was wondering just now if there was a way to do it where I could use Mathematica but still only from within the Wolfram|Alpha search bar?