# How to solve the general formula by the recursive formula in MMA?

Tags: recursion

I want to solve this problem $T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2T(i),T(1)=1$, I want to know how to solve this in MMA?

### My thinking:

I have tried `RSolve` command, but the output is the same as the input.

$$RSolve[a[n]==\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2*a[i],a,n]$$

Comment: One way to solve this in MMA is to use https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40/is-it-possible-to-invoke-the-oeis-from-mathematica  Your sequence does show up in the oeis as http://oeis.org/A025192

Comment: @Bill It's an excellent site! While it seems a little bit tricky. Can I solve it with RSolve or something else?

Comment: Solve it analytically or numerically?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ ,I hope I can get an analytically expression.

Comment: Your defining equation is inconsistent with the initial condition for `n=1`: `t[1]==Sum[2 t[i],{i,1,0}]`.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"`T[n] == Sum[2 T[i], {i, 1, n - 1}]`" isn't really a (single) recurrence equation, so `RSolve` won't do much with it.  (It's a different recurrence equation for each choice of $n$.)  It is analogous to asking `DSolve` to do something useful with $f(x) = \int_{1}^{x}f(u) \,\mathrm{d}u$, which it won't because there is no derivative here.  Here, we ask `DSolve` to solve an integral equation (or generally, an integrodifferential equation) in the same way we have asked `RSolve` to solve a summatory equation (or generally, a summation-recurrence equation).

Other solutions here have suggested first manipulating the equation by hand, then using `RSolve`.  This is to convert your equation into a (single) recurrence equation.  To convert the analogous integral to something `DSolve` will make progress with, we make Mathematica apply the fundamental theorem of calculus for us, then DSolve makes progress.

```
D[#,x]& /@ (f[x] == Integrate[f[u],{u,1,x}])
DSolve[%, f[x], x]
(*  f'[x] = f[x]  
    {{ f[x] -> E^C[1] }}
 *)
```

We need to do the same thing here (and we'll include `T[1]==1`).

```
DifferenceDelta[#, n]& /@ (T[n] == Sum[2 T[i], {i, 1, n - 1}])
RSolve[{ %, T[1]==1}, T[n], n]
(*  -T[n] + T[1 + n] == 2 T[n]
    {{ T[n] -> 3^(-1+n) }}
 *)
```

Answer (score 6):

It is easy to deal with this problem in the numerical way. Besides the approach involved with memoization as [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) used, another is to use `Nest`:

```
Nest[Append[#, 2 Total[#]] &, {1}, 10]
FindSequenceFunction[%[[2 ;;]], n]
```

generate

```
{1, 2, 6, 18, 54, 162, 486, 1458, 4374, 13122, 39366}

2 3^(-1 + n)
```

This means that $ T(n) = 2\times 3^{n-2} $ for $ n = 2,3,4,... $.

Answer (score 6):

This can also be seen as $T(n+1)-T(n)=2 T(n)\iff T(n+1)=3 T(n)$ for $n>1$, so$T(n)= 3T(n-1)=9 T(n-2)=...=3^{n-2}T(2)$ and $T(2)=2$. Therefore, 
$ T(1)=1,T(n)=2\cdot 3^{n-2}, for \quad n>1$

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[T];
T[1] = 1;
T[n_Integer?Positive] := T[n] = Sum[2*T[i], {i, 1, n - 1}];
```

Generate a sequence from the recursion

```
seq = T /@ Range[10]

(* {1, 2, 6, 18, 54, 162, 486, 1458, 4374, 13122} *)
```

Use [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to find the general formula

```
f[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]
```

[image]

The general formula is expressed as a [`DifferenceRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html)

Verifying that the recursion and the general formula are equivalent even for values outside the original sequence:

```
(T /@ Range[100]) == (f /@ Range[100])

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by [`Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12924/%CE%91%CE%BB%CE%AD%CE%BE%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%B4%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%82-%CE%96%CE%B5%CE%B3%CE%B3or) for `n > 1`

```
Clear[T2];
T2[1] = 1;
T2[n_Integer?Positive] = FindSequenceFunction[{#, T[#]} & /@ Range[2, 10], n]

(* 2 3^(-2 + n) *)
```

Checking,

```
(T /@ Range[100]) == (f /@ Range[100]) == (T2 /@ Range[100])

(* True *)
```

Comment: Why you obtain the right solution, the pedagogical value of your answer is low, as it teaches guessing not solving...

Comment: @yarchik - Presumably, a pedagogical purposes of this forum is to teach/learn the capabilities of Mathematica. Even when rigor is desired or required, guessing can provide insight and a useful first step (e.g., proof by induction). WRI has spent considerable resources on such methods. See also: `FindDistribution`, `FindFormula`, `FindGeneratingFunction`, `FindLinearRecurrence`, `RootApproximant`, et al. (`Names["Find*"]`)

Answer (score 3):

Using @ubdqn's observations with `RSolve`:

```
RSolve[{t[n] == 3 t[n - 1], t[2] == 2}, t[n], n]
```

> {{t[n] -> 2 3^(-2 + n)}}

Comment: I think among of all answers, your solution approaches the problem in a very systematic way that can be recommended in many cases. First, problem is manually simplified (@ubpdqn) using mathematical intuition  and only then MA is used to work out the details.

Comment: @yarchik, thank you. Without some pre-analysis I don't see  a way to come up with the correct initial condition (especially `t[1] ==1` is given as part of the problem description).

Comment: That is true, the initial condition `t[1]==1` is inconsistent with `t[1]=Sum[2 t[i],{i,1,0}]` and therefore needs to be put by hand.