# Is it possible to find a limit of a sequence given by its recurrence relation?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, sequence, difference-equations

I need to calculate a limit of a sequence given by its recurrence relation. I tried the following:

```
Limit[DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, n}, {
      - n (1 + n)^2 (5 + 2 n) y[n] 
      - (1 + n) (3 + n) (11 + 14 n + 4 n^2) y[1 + n] 
      + (-77 - 128 n - 69 n^2 - 12 n^3) y[2 + n] 
      + (29 + 84 n + 79 n^2 + 30 n^3 + 4 n^4) y[3 + n] 
      + (3 + n)^3 (3 + 2 n) y[4 + n] == 0, 
      y[1] == 0, y[2] == -1, y[3] == 1/8, y[4] == -215/216
  }]][n], n -> Infinity]
```

but it returned unevaluated.

Answer (score 11):

First, you can try to apply the [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FunctionExpand.html) command to the `DifferenceRoot` object. If it is able to find a closed form of the sequence, then the `Limit` might be able to find an exact symbolic limit.

To find a numerical approximation, you can use the [`SequenceLimit`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SequenceLimit.html) command. In general, it does not guarantee to give the correct result, but if your sequence behaves 'nicely' then you might be able to obtain the correct result with a very high precision:

```
In[1]:= SequenceLimit[N[Table[
        DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, n}, {
            - n (1 + n)^2 (5 + 2 n) y[n] 
            - (1 + n) (3 + n) (11 + 14 n + 4 n^2) y[1 + n] 
            + (-77 - 128 n - 69 n^2 - 12 n^3) y[2 + n] 
            + (29 + 84 n + 79 n^2 + 30 n^3 + 4 n^4) y[3 + n] 
            + (3 + n)^3 (3 + 2 n) y[4 + n] == 0, 
            y[1] == 0, y[2] == -1, y[3] == 1/8, y[4] == -215/216
        }]][n],
    {n, 1, 500}], 200]]

Out[1]= -0.442460189377912495218798219174656335184133627022583585864263293471236392630861
```

Plugging the numeric result in the [`TranscendentalRecognize`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35/7288) function with a wide enough set of transcendental constants, you might get its possible closed form:

```
-1/12 (-π^2 Log[2] + 4 Log[2]^3 + 9 Zeta[3])
```