# Have Mathematica recognize physical constant

Tags: physicalconstants-package

Say Barry, could you abuse the "answer your own question" feature of StackExchange to answer the currently on-hold [Recognize physical constants?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104178/recognize-physical-constants) ?