# Volume bounded by two spheres

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, computational-geometry

I'd like to find the volume of the region of intersection of the spheres defined by
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=4$$
and:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+4x-2y+4z+5=0$$

I tried:

```
a = ImplicitRegion[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 4 x - 2 y + 4 z + 5 <= 0 && 
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4, {x, y, z}]
```

Then I tried:

```
Volume[a]
```

But I had to abort.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ouch! I entered the wrong equation. In my code above I have  $x^2+y^2+z^2+4x-2y+4x+5\le 0$. I entered $4x$ instead of $4z$. I should have entered $x^2+y^2+z^2+4x-2y+4z+5\le 0$

Comment: @Xavier How about an exact answer, which should be $11\pi/12$ if I enter the correct inequality $x^2+y^2+z^2+4x-2y+4z+5\le0$. Any way to get this exact answer?

Comment: I waited for `Volume` to finish.  It doesn't give an answer.  It is very strange that Boole and Integrate work but Volume doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

`Boole` is a way:

```
V = Integrate[
 Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 4 x - 2 y + 4 x + 5 <= 0 && 
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}]
```

The result:

[image]

i.e., $V\approx 6.35166$.

---

**EDIT:** It seems I was lucky: after correcting the erroneous $x$ to $z$ the `Integrate` of `Boole` takes a ridiculously long time to return an enourmous integral over $x$. Nonetheless, the initial idea is still valid when one aims at obtaining an approximate result via `NIntegrate`:

```
v = NIntegrate[
 Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 4 x - 2 y + 4 z + 5 <= 0 && 
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0581, 2.87979}

The above takes a comparable amount of time as Xavier's approach (i.e., 0.0414 on my computer).

---

**EDIT2:** I've tested every method from [Can Mathematica propose an exact value based on an approximate one?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16/can-mathematica-propose-an-exact-value-based-on-an-approximate-one), and only the [Python script by Simon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35/22013) yielded as a result $\frac{11\pi}{12}$:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps = 15;
print identify(2.87979320312696707163, ['pi'])
```

> pi*((264-sqrt(0))/288)

Comment: `And` should be `&&`. `And` is a function requiring two or more arguments. `&&` is the infix form.

Answer (score 10):

*Update: Region equation changed after OP's edit.*

---

In case you're only after a non-exact result, you can change the value of the option `WorkingPrecision` (by default `Infinity` for `Volume`) or change the method. These give a result pretty fast:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 4 x - 2 y + 4 z + 5 <= 0 && 
                     x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4, {x, y, z}]

RepeatedTiming[Volume[reg, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]]
(* {0.076, 2.87979} *)

RepeatedTiming[Volume[reg, Method -> "NIntegrate"]]
(* {0.078, 2.87979} *)
```

Answer (score 10):

Correcting the $z-x $ issue and using

```
Expand[(x + 2)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z + 2)^2] - 4 == 
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 4 x - 2 y + 4 z + 5
```

yields true-> centres of spheres.

Therefore, using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html) to derive analytic solution:

```
c = {-2, 1, -2};
Show[ContourPlot3D[{(x + 2)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z + 2)^2 == 4, 
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 4}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{{0, 0, 0}, c}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, c}]}
  ]]
r = 2;
R = 2;
vol[a_, b_] := Pi (4 a + b) (2 a - b)^2/12;
vol[R, Norm@c]
```

[image]

Comment: @ShutaoTang I remembered that I had come across it some time ago...luck I guess :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's just one more way to get the answer,

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ RegionIntersection[
   Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 2],
   Ball[{-2, 1, -2}, 2]]]
(* 2.87979 *)
```

Sadly,

```
Volume [RegionIntersection[
 Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 2],
 Ball[{-2, 1, -2}, 2]]
```

won't give an exact answer in any reasonable time in the same way that `Area@RegionIntersection[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{-2, 1}, 2]]` does.

Comment: +1, good old NIntegrate...hope you are well:)