# How might one obtain a high-precision estimate of the integral over [0,1] of a specific function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have the following function

```
(1/(35 \[Pi]^3 (-1 + 
t^2)^13))65536 t (-(-1 + t) (1 + t) (363 + 10310 t^2 + 58673 t^4 + 
  101548 t^6 + 58673 t^8 + 10310 t^10 + 363 t^12) + 
140 (1 + t^2) (1 + 48 t^2 + 393 t^4 + 832 t^6 + 393 t^8 + 48 t^10 +
   t^12) Log[t]) (t - t^3 + (-1 + t^4) ArcTanh[t] + 
t^2 (-4 PolyLog[2, t] + PolyLog[2, t^2]))^2
```

and would like to obtain a high-precision estimate of its integral over [0,1] (which I would then input, say to WolframAlpha, to check for a possible exact value). I've encountered numerical problems near `t = 1`.

Comment: How high a precision do you need?

Comment: Thanks bbgodfrey! Well, I'm basically (perhaps wildly) speculating that there might be some underlying exact value of note (maybe even a rational number), based on some prior considerations. So, if WolframAlpha, say, doesn't indicate such a value for a given precision, I could just try to get more numerical precision and try again. Of course, such a process could not go on for ever. I would imagine that perhaps an estimate accurate to say 15 places might settle the issue.

Comment: Try 0.450160328041638434796903399409, but I am not aware of any capabilities that WolframAlpha has that Mathematica does not.

Comment: Can you maybe describe the provenance of this function?

Comment: For a possible exact value: [Can Mathematica propose an exact value based on an approximate one?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16/can-mathematica-propose-an-exact-value-based-on-an-approximate-one) and an [example application](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125913/22013). Try also `RootApproximant` with `ToRadicals`.

Comment: Thanks, J. M. To be very brief at this moment, I'm trying to find the complex analogue (\chi_2(\epsilon)) to (\chi_1(\epsilon)), that is eq. (9) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01410.pdf, but my analysis/approach may not be entirely correct. Also, bbgodfrey, I understand that one can evoke  the WolframAlpha machinery in Mathematica itself. The suggested value 0.450160328041638434796903399409 doesn't seem to lead to anything of particular note--so I'm inclined, at this point, to suspect that I'm not fully correct in my attempted extension of the indicated Attila-Lovas eq. (9).

Comment: To add to my just-posted comment, I was working under a ("Dyson-index/random-matrix") conjecture that  \chi_2(\epsilon) would be proportional to the square of  (\chi_1(\epsilon)). Getting things fully right here, however, seems quite tricky/challenging.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[t_] = (1/(35 \[Pi]^3 (-1 + t^2)^13)) 65536 t (-(-1 + t) (1 + 
        t) (363 + 10310 t^2 + 58673 t^4 + 101548 t^6 + 58673 t^8 + 
        10310 t^10 + 363 t^12) + 
     140 (1 + t^2) (1 + 48 t^2 + 393 t^4 + 832 t^6 + 393 t^8 + 
        48 t^10 + t^12) Log[t]) (t - t^3 + (-1 + t^4) ArcTanh[t] + 
      t^2 (-4 PolyLog[2, t] + PolyLog[2, t^2]))^2;
```

High [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) is required to `Plot`

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image]

```
Table[
   {wp, NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, 1},
      WorkingPrecision -> wp,
      MaxRecursion -> Infinity] //
     N[#, 15] &}, {wp, 15, 40, 
    5}] //
  Grid // Quiet
```

[image]

So the integral stabilizes to 15 decimal places at a `WorkingPrecision` of around 35

```
(int = NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 35, 
     MaxRecursion -> Infinity]) // N[#, 15] & // Quiet

(*  0.450160328041638  *)
```

Using [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html) to rationalize

```
intr = int // Round[#, 10^-15] &

(*  225080164020819/500000000000000  *)

intr // N[#, 15] &

(*  0.450160328041638  *)
```

Using [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

```
intr2 = Rationalize[int, 10*^-16]

(*  18677965/41491806  *)

intr2 // N[#, 15] &

(*  0.450160328041638  *)
```