# Can FindFormula or FindSequenceFunction be used to identify a formula for a number?

Tags: number-representation

This is closely related to: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2361727/10063 and is a *new version* of [Can Mathematica propose an exact value based on an approximate one?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16/534).

In Wolfram|Alpha I can input an approximate number, say 1.46342 and get a closed form expression that approximates it,

$\qquad 1.46342 \approx \sqrt{\pi - 1}$

Is there a way to do this in Mathematica? According to [Can Mathematica propose an exact value based on an approximate one?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16/534) (which is an older thread), there seems to be no canonical way. However, the functions `FindFormula` and `FindSequenceFunction` seem to be very related to this. I wonder if there is a way to "hack" them into accomplishing this.

Comment: See [`9362`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16/9362)

Comment: @CarlWoll So it looks like there is no standard way of doing it inside Mathematica. Hmm, since that thread is a bit old (dating 2012) I'll reformulate my question, to address specifically a way to *hack* `FindFormula` and `FindSequenceFunction` to do this. I just have a feeling this is possible. I think that makes this question different, agree?

Comment: What's wrong with the answer given in the duplicate question: `WolframAlpha[ToString[num], IncludePods -> "PossibleClosedForm"]`?

Comment: @yohbs It uses `WolframAlpha`. Try to look at tit this way: Can you do it with Mathematica *offline*?