# How to using the method of undetermined coefficients in this equation?

Tags: equation-solving, coefficients

I want to find the rational numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ satisfying the condition

$$\displaystyle \int _ { 5 } ^ { 21 } \frac { \mathrm { d } x } { x \cdot \sqrt { x + 4 } } = a \ln 3 + b \ln 5 + c \ln 7.$$
I solve by hand.

```
Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 4]), {x, 5, 21}]
```

> 1/2 Log[15/7]

From here, I got, $ a = \dfrac{1}{2} $, $ b = \dfrac{1}{2} $, $ c = -\dfrac{1}{2} .$

How can I tell *Mathematica* to do that?

With *Maple*, I got the answer directly
[image]

[image]

Comment: You're just calculating the integral rather than solving the equation in _Maple_. If such results are desired for you, simply `Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 4]), {x, 5, 21}] // PowerExpand // Expand`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{a/d, b/e, c/f} /. 
 FindInstance[Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 4]), {x, 5, 21}] == 
   a Log[3]/d + b Log[5]/e + c Log[7]/f, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, Integers]
```

> {{1/2, 1/2, -(1/2)}}

Comment: How about equation? I don't get the result?
`Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f]
{a/d, b/e} /. 
 FindInstance[
  Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 16]), {x, 9, 33}] == 
   a Log[3]/d + b Log[11]/e, {a, d, b, e}, Integers]`

Comment: @minhthien_2016, as the message says, _The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist._ You can try `Reduce`: for example, `Reduce[{Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 16]), {x, 9, 33}] == 
   a Log[3]/d + b Log[11]/e, 
  And @@ Thread[-5 <= {a, d, b, e} <= 5]}, {a, d, b, e}, Integers]` gives a solution.

Comment: `1/4 Log[27/11]` can be written `3/4 Log[3] - 1/4 Log[11]`

Answer (score 2):

Not as automated as [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr)'s solution, but the following works:

```
eq = Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 4]), {x, 5, 21}] == a Log@3 + b Log@5 + c Log@7
(* 1/2 Log[15/7] == a Log[3] + b Log[5] + c Log[7] *)

PowerExpand@eq
(* 1/2 (Log[3] + Log[5] - Log[7]) == a Log[3] + b Log[5] + c Log[7] *)

Collect[Subtract @@ %, Log[_]] == 0
(* (1/2 - a) Log[3] + (1/2 - b) Log[5] + (-(1/2) - c) Log[7] == 0 *)

Cases[%, coe_ Log[_] :> Solve[coe == 0], Infinity] // Flatten
(* {a -> 1/2, b -> 1/2, c -> -(1/2)} *)
```

This method also handles the new added example `Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 16]), {x, 9, 33}] == a Log[3] + b Log[11]`.

Comment: When I tried
`eq1 = Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 16]), {x, 9, 33}] == a Log@3 + b Log@5;
PowerExpand@eq1;
Collect[Subtract @@ %, Log[_]] == 0;
Cases[%, coe_ Log[_] :> Solve[coe == 0], Infinity] // Flatten`

I got `{a -> 3/4, b -> 0}`. I think, It is wrong.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 The equation itself is wrong. The `Log@5` should be `Log@11`.

Comment: Yes. I think, the answer, It can not be found.

Comment: As already mentioned, this solution is not a fully automated solution, error handling should be done manually.

Comment: I am looking forward to a genenral method.

Comment: Then you should clarify all of these in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting your question to mean that you want logarithms of rational numbers to be expressed purely in terms of logarithms of primes. If so, one can use a replacement rule:

```
{Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 4]), {x, 5, 21}], 
 Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[x + 16]), {x, 9, 33}]} // Simplify
   {1/2 Log[15/7], 1/4 Log[27/11]}

% /. Log[r_Rational] :> (Total[#2 Log[#1] & @@@ FactorInteger[Numerator[r]]] - 
                         Total[#2 Log[#1] & @@@ FactorInteger[Denominator[r]]]) // Expand
   {Log[3]/2 + Log[5]/2 - Log[7]/2, 3 Log[3]/4 - Log[11]/4}
```

---

Alternatively, one can use `FindIntegerNullVector[]`, similar to what was done in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11468):

```
-Rest[#]/First[#] &[FindIntegerNullVector[{1/2 Log[15/7], Log[3], Log[5], Log[7]}]]
   {1/2, 1/2, -1/2}

-Rest[#]/First[#] &[FindIntegerNullVector[{1/4 Log[27/11], Log[3], Log[11]}]]
   {3/4, -1/4}
```